# weird black lines crossing through my donut icing

Tags: python, mesh, error

So I am building a Donut in Blender. I am following Blender Guru's tutorial. The problem is that I have made the icing appear dribbled, But there are some weird black lines crossing through the mesh. I dont know what problem is this, cause its my first time in blender. Any help would be appreciated. Here are some screenshots.[image]

[image]

Comment: Those look like you extruded some single vertices, but it's hard to tell because of the subdivision surface modifier. You can "turn it off" in the viewport by clicking the little icon that looks like a TV screen next to the camera icon (above the catmull-clark/simple option) in the modifier properties panel on the right side. That will let you get a better look at the _actual_ underlying geometry. If they are stray edges, enter edge select mode, select them, right click and select "dissolve edges".

Comment: Can you simplify the message

Comment: I have turned off the subdivision surface

Comment: Ok, with the modifier off, do you see the black lines (my guess is they're simply "loose" edges)?

Comment: Yes. I think it is a bug.

Comment: I'm thinking you can probably select and delete those lines.